# Question about Windows API

Tags: windows

I have a code which is running on DOS Box in windows 7...However my question is whether my code is using the Windoows API or not? Below are the headers file which I am using...

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<process.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you take a look at that code? If there are any Windows specific APIs being used, it won't be too hard to find them by looking at included header files.

DOSBox can run Windows 3.1 and associated programs, but if your program runs outside of Windows 3.1, then you can be pretty sure that no Windows APIs are being used.

Comment: @vks: from the look of those header files, I'd say it's a DOS program. You've got `dos.h` which is DOS only, you've got `conio.h` which is used in old MS DOS compilers to create text interfaces. These header files suggest your code is pretty old and probably can be compiled only by older compilers, ala Turbo C.

Comment: thank you so much for your comments...and i am able to compile the program, but my question is program using windoows api...if yes, then which one is using the same...

Comment: @vks: since there is no `windows.h` header file which contains declarations for all functions of Windows API, and no `WinMain()` function which is mandatory for Windows programs, and if you can compile the program -> that's pretty strong evidence that there is no presence of Windows API in your program.

Answer (score 2):

These headers are not part of the Windows API, and in fact, it's unlikely that your code will compile at all using a compiler other than Borland Turbo C/C++.

It looks like you're using mostly proprietary Borland libraries. For example, `graphics.h` allows you to draw graphics in a text-based MS-DOS environment. It's not supported under Windows at all.

Even the header files like `conio.h` that you'll probably find in other compilers may not be compatible with the one you're using in your code. The library functions declared by `conio.h` vary somewhat from one compiler to another.

As a general rule, every program that uses the Windows API will include [`windows.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h), and perhaps some additional child header files, depending on the specific functionality needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the information you have received so far is too general. The headers that are included dont show you everything.

> 1) the compiler used will include headers **behind-the-scenes**
>
> 2) the **librarys linked** are only loosly coupled to the headers that you specified

Example:

- if you use MinGW and include no headers explicitly it will link to stdlib.h behind the scenes and this will be linked to the Windows API without you ever knowing it.
- if you then call malloc() it will be translated to HeapAlloc (Windows API) by the mingw-Headers and obviously linked to the Windows API.